# Templated Functions.. ERROR: template-id does not match any template declaration

Tags: c++, generics, strcmp, function-templates

I have written **a function template** and **an explicitly specialized templated function** which simply takes in 3 arguments and calculates the biggest among them and prints it.

The specialized function is causing an error,whereas the template works fine.
But I want to work with **char* type**.

This is the error I get=> 
`error: template-id ‘Max<>’ for ‘void Max(char, char, char)’ does not match any template declaration`

**Following is my code:**

```
    template <typename T>
    void Max(T& a,T& b,T& c)
    {
            if(a > b && a >> c)
            {
                    cout << "Max: " << a << endl;
            }
            else if(b > c && b > a)
            {
                    cout << "Max: " << b << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                    cout << "Max: " << c << endl;
            }
    }

    template <>
    void Max(char* a,char* b,char* c)
    {
            if(strcmp(a,b) > 0 )
            {
                    cout << "Max: " << a << endl;
            }
            else if(strcmp(b,c) > 0)
            {
                    cout << "Max: " << b << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                    cout << "Max: " << b << endl;
            }
}
```

Comment: First make original signature proper. template < typename T > void Max( T& a, T& b, T& c)

Comment: In my case, it's caused by adding const to returnt type specilizatoin hence causing mismatch with primary template function .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to take the pointers by reference:

```
template <> 
void Max(char*& a,char*& b,char*& c)
```

That said, it would be better *not* to use an explicit specialization and instead just overload the function:

```
void Max(char* a, char* b, char* c)
```

It's almost always a bad idea to specialize function templates.  For more, see Herb Sutter's ["Why Not Specialize Function Templates?"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and fixed it by using typedef:

```
typedef char * charPtr;
template <>
void Max(charPtr &a, charPtr &b, charPtr &c)
```